# Codename one java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Tags: java, codenameone, socket-timeout-exception

I'm working on a project on Codename One in which I need to check certain addresses. If the address doesn't exist, a variable in my code, named lectura should be 404. However when I find an address which doesn't exist, my code stops and displays a message on screen thats says java.net.SocketTimeoutException with the options cancel or retry. I need my program to know the address didn't exist and to move on, not to pause. My code is:

```
public int readCNO(String cantidad, int number){


    ConnectionRequest r3 = new ConnectionRequest();
    r3.setUrl("http://" + ipZona + "/arduino/" + cantidad + "!" + type + "/" + Integer.toString(number));

    r3.setPost(false);
    r3.setDuplicateSupported(true);
    r3.setTimeout(100);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r3);
    r3.addResponseListener(new ActionListener()
    {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
        {
            try
            {
                NetworkEvent event = (NetworkEvent) ev;
                byte[] data= (byte[]) event.getMetaData();
                String decodedData = new String(data,"UTF-8");
                System.out.println(decodedData);
                lectura = Integer.parseInt(decodedData.trim());

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                //ex.printStackTrace();
                lectura = 404;
            }

        }


    });
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(r3);
    //NetworkManager.getInstance().killAndWait(r3);



    return lectura;
}
```

Help really appreciated!

David.

The complete exception is shown afterwards, but It doesn't refer to any of my classes, not where the code above is, nor where it is called.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.getResponseCode(JavaSEPort.java:4557)
    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:330)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:261)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.getResponseCode(JavaSEPort.java:4557)
    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:330)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:261)
    at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Comment: I recently met a guy named David.  Dude was a complete jerk.

Comment: Can you tell us at which line the `SocketTimeoutException` happens?  You most likely are receiving that Exception outside the try/catch block.  What is `lectura` before you set it to `404`?  Make sure you don't return an empty primitive data type variable.

Comment: I can assure you that's not me, I try to be a nice guy! The exact exception I'll post it as an "answer" for the question for it is too long and wont fit as a comment.

Comment: Just edit your original question.  Don't post it as an answer.  Also, make sure you point out to us which exact line the exception is at.  Don't *just* show us the stack trace.

Comment: lectura is just defined as int lectura; before it is used in the code shown above. I edited the question but in the stack trace I couldn't find any reference to my classes, not where the code is, nor where it is called.

Comment: I think I found my problem and why my try catch is not catching this. In the package com.codenameone1.io.ConnectionRequest, there is a line of code that opens a dialog. I.e., if(Display.isInitialized() &&
                Dialog.show("Exception", err.toString() + ": for URL " + url + "\n" + err.getMessage(), "Retry", "Cancel")) {
            retry();
        } which is the message I get and that stops my application. However I can't edit that file, it seems it is read-only, do you perhaps know any solution? David

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with an answer from this post [catching unknown host exception in codename one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598241/catching-unknown-host-exception-in-codename-one), the code is:

```
NetworkManager.getInstance().addErrorListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //handle your error here consume the event
        evt.consume();
    }
});
```